# Offsets committed out of order with Spark DataSource API V2 Hive Streaming Sink

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using sink to save Spark(2.3) Structured Streaming DataFrame into Hive table with a [custom sink implementation](https://github.com/jerryshao/spark-hive-streaming-sink).

The code is as follows.

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 19191).load().as[String]


val query = df.map { s => val records = s.split(",") assert(records.length >= 4)
        (records(0).toInt, records(1), records(2), records(3))
     }


query.selectExpr("_1 as eid", "_2 as name", "_3 as salary", "_4 as designation").
      writeStream.
      format("hive-streaming").
      option("metastore", ".....").
      option("db", "test").
      option("table", "test_employee").
      option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoints/employee/checkpoint").
      queryName("socket-hive-streaming").
      start()
```

This would lead to following runtime error.

```
ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query socket-hive-streaming [id =  ......, runId = ......] terminated with error
java.lang.RuntimeException: Offsets committed out of order: 1 followed by 0
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.TextSocketSource.commit(socket.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:356)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:355)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:338)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Delete/clear your checkpoint: `/checkpoints/employee/checkpoint` on your machine
2. Using the other source that maintains offset, like Kafka

The reason you meet this issue is that **the socket doesn't maintain offset information**.

When you restart your job which receives input data from `socket 9999`, the first thing that your job does is trying to recover the state from `/checkpoints/employee/checkpoint`, and it finds that your current offset that has been recorded is `1`. Then you input other messages to `socket 9999`, your job finds that the offset from `socket 9999` is `0`. So it throws this exception.

Comment: is there an alternative to these 2 ways? I can't use Kafka and I want my MQ to recover from failure that's why I don't want to delete the checkpoint folder contents.