# Datasource V2 Reader (Spark Structured Streaming) - offsets out of order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming, amazon-efs

I am currently implementing two custom readers using the V2 api for a spark structured streaming job. After the job runs for ~30-60 minutes, it bombs with:

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Offsets committed out of order: 608799 followed by 2982`

I am repurposing the examples found [here](https://github.com/hienluu/wikiedit-streaming/blob/master/streaming-receiver/src/main/scala/org/twitterstreaming/receiver/TwitterStreamingSource.scala) and it is bombing at line: 206.

Instead of using the twitter stream that is provided in the example I am implementing it for JMS & SQS.

My question is: has anyone encountered this issue? Or is there something wrong with that implementation?

Code snippet:

```scala
override def commit(end: Offset): Unit = {
    internalLog(s"** commit($end) lastOffsetCommitted: $lastOffsetCommitted")

    val newOffset = TwitterOffset.convert(end).getOrElse(
      sys.error(s"TwitterStreamMicroBatchReader.commit() received an offset ($end) that did not " +
        s"originate with an instance of this class")
    )

    val offsetDiff = (newOffset.offset - lastOffsetCommitted.offset).toInt

    if (offsetDiff < 0) {
      sys.error(s"Offsets committed out of order: $lastOffsetCommitted followed by $end")
    }

    tweetList.trimStart(offsetDiff)
    lastOffsetCommitted = newOffset
}
```

I can't find an answer with my usual outlets. I did, however, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493552/offsets-committed-out-of-order-with-spark-datasource-api-v2-hive-streaming-sink). One point that was made is to delete checkpoint data - which doesn't seem like a viable solution in a production system. The other was that the source system doesn't maintain offset information? I was under the impression that spark would be handling the offset information by itself. If this second point is the problem, how can I ensure that the source system handles this paradigm.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

**Edit:** Looking at the MicroBatchReader interface, the documentation for commit says:

```
    /**
     * Informs the source that Spark has completed processing all data for offsets less than or
     * equal to `end` and will only request offsets greater than `end` in the future.
     */
    void commit(Offset end);
```

So the question becomes, why is spark sending me commit offsets that has already been committed?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it helps someone,

I should have added more information to the question - this job is running on EMR and is using EFS to checkpoint data.

The problem occurred when I used Amazon's `amazon-efs-utils` to mount EFS. For some reason each worker was not able to see the other workers' reads and writes - as if EFS didn't mount.

The solution was to switch to `nfs-utils` to mount EFS (per AWS instructions) so that each worker could accurately read the checkpoint data.